# Visual Studio 2015 does not show Unicode last changed charrecter?

Tags: unicode, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS 2015 and TFS 2013 update 4.

I was able to see the name of person who last modified/updated and so on above 
method classes but right now it just show author names which are in Unicode by question mark

What's the problem?

[image]

**Updated:**

Now all of Unicode charecters are gone even in c# files

Comment: Did you change anything recently? Did you see this specific author name before? Did you try to refresh the codelens by right click it?

Comment: In addition, You can check the history of this file to see whether you can see the author.

Comment: no i didn't change anything.

Comment: @1AmirJalali, what's the language for the author name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
 Tools ====> options ===> Environment ====> show settings for : CodeLens
```

and then changed Font type to tahoma.

I check vs on other machines the font on others were sets to calibri but Unicode characters displayed correctly

for more info you can go to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218.aspx

How do I change the font and color for CodeLens?

A: Go to Tools, Options, Environment, Fonts and Colors.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio.
2. Delete all the cached data in the folder %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services\6.0\
3. Restart Visual Studio and re-open the solution from TFS.

Comment: the first thing i did was deleting cached data and all of other caches

Comment: Did you check the history of this file? Can you see the author in history?

Comment: Yes the author name can be seen in history

Comment: Did you try on another client machine?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:
1). Add the author name's language in Control Panel.
2). Open that file with "CSharp Editor with Encoding".
3). Reset VS to the default settings: devenv /ResetSettings

Comment: No success i did all of the above mentioned steps.

Comment: @1AmirJalali, how about you clicking on "4 authors, 8 changes" CodeLens in your above screenshot? Does the author name displayed correctly?